# Is there any way to locate an element by its childs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to locate an element that doesn't differ from some other elements, but its child differs from others in class.The HTML:

```
<div class="grid x4" id="grid">
    <div><span class="fa fa-book" style="display: none;"></span></div> #⬅for example this element
    <div><span class="fa fa-birthday-cake" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-bolt" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-cube" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-coffee" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-car" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-birthday-cake" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-book" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-cube" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-bomb" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-car" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-bomb" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-cubes" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-coffee" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-cubes" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div><span class="fa fa-bolt" style="display: none;"></span></div>
</div>
```

Taking a look at [the website](http://zzzscore.com/memory/) might be helpful. The following code can locate the child but is there anyway to locate the element(not the child)?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://zzzscore.com/memory/')
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class= "fa fa-book"]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you chose parents with an xpath
in this case when you know that parent tag is div just use this:

```py
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class= "fa fa-book"]/parent::div')
```

If you wouldn't know what is exactly the parent you can replace tag name with `*`

Comment: When I add .click() it shows: elements[0].click()
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: seems there is not such an element but there is

Comment: @Pautodidactic the only exception I get when I try to do ``elements[0].click()`` is ``ElementClickInterceptedException`` which makes sense unless you wait until the element is clickable. Could you show the code where you assign ``elements`` and what you do later with it?

Comment: If you are just looking for the first element, just use `find_element` (singular) and you can just do `element.click()`.

Comment: its worth noting you can also access the parent with '../'